# How to use components in my custom js file in Laravel and Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm new to Laravel and Vue.js. I created a simple Laravel/Vue.js project like this post: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-and-vue-js-crud-with-pagination-example-and-demo-from-scratchexample.html

Now I want to add date-picker to my blade files: https://talkhabi.github.io/vue-persian-datetime-picker/#/installation

However, when I import component to my js file (for example `item.js`), I get the following error message:

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : [es6-modules-getting-started-gotchas](https://medium.com/@mattlag/es6-modules-getting-started-gotchas-2ad154f38e2e)

Answer (score 0):

Your import statements must come first at the beginning of your JS files. No import statements should come after regular code.

Comment: i add codes at the top of item.js file. but i get again that error message.

Comment: i add (import VuePersianDatetimePicker from 'vue-persian-datetime-picker';) before this line in item.js : Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');